# CaseHistory Filtering records

Tags: history-tracking

Looking at the CaseHistory data, it appears that there are two entries for (nearly every)  tracked field change. If I understand correctly, one entry represents the foreign key, the other is the actual before/after value. How can I reliably filter an extract onthis table so that I can ignore the before/after values. (i.e. I only want the foreign keys)

Also, there are entries that don't relate to tracked fields: created and close. Does anyone have any documentation about other such entries in this table?

One more question, is the timestamp for a batch of changes atomic? i.e. is there any way to tie a group of changes together? for example if you change the status and owner at the same time, can I be sure that they will get the same timestamp? (and not be fractially different on occasion!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the `CaseHistory` table will only have two rows when the changed field is a lookup field (such as the `AccountId` or `ContactId`).

[image]

If you want to ignore the before/after values of the lookup fields, you'll have to a) know that the value in the `Field` column is a lookup field and then determine the key prefix for that field (Contact is 003, Account is 001) and thus ignore any row's NewValue or OldValue doesn't start with the keyprefix (hack-y)

As you can see in the table above, when Field is 'created', there is no NewValue or OldValue. The doc [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/object_reference/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_objects_casehistory.htm) lists four special values for CaseHistory in addition to created and closed:

- `ownerAssignment`—The owner of the case was changed.
- `ownerAccepted`—A user took ownership of a case from a queue.
- `ownerEscalated`—The owner of the case was changed due to case escalation.
- `external`—A user made the case visible to customers in the Customer Self-Service Portal.

As for whether the field updates in a single Save (DML event) have the same timestamp, the picture suggests they do - in fact, the time resolution is only to the nearest second. Milliseconds are shown as 0000.  As this is the only field you have to work with, you might as well assume that n rows with the same `createdDate` occurred as part of the same transaction.